# Does Terraform provide a mechanism to find the provider version?

Tags: terraform, versioning

Other than reading `.terraform.lock.hcl` is there a mechanisms in Terraform to find the version of the providers I am using with the cli interface?

I don't see the version when I run `terraform providers` or the ability to add a `-v` flag (or another flag) under `terraform providers --help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the version of your providers with `terraform version`

```
❯ terraform version
Terraform v1.1.9
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.75.1
```

### With [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)

```
❯ terraform version -json | jq .provider_selections
{
  "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws": "3.75.1"
}
```

terraform version -json | jq .provider_selections

I opened a [UX Improvement case on GitHub #31048](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/31048#issue-1236104011)